# symfony 2- super admin role in role hierarchy

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 role hierarchy. I would like to create a role like super admin that always returns true for `is_granted('ROLE_ANY')`

I can't do it manually in the role hierarchy, because I create roles dynamically.

Is there a way to have something like a wildcard (like: `ROLE_SPECIAL_ADMIN: [ROLE_*]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a custom voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) that grants access as soon as the current user has `ROLE_SPECIAL_SUPER_HERO_ADMIN`.

Comment: and how to use it in twig